# Modifiying Users Table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am just starting out with Laravel but am not new PHP frameworks.

I have Laravel 5.4 and have run `php artisan make:auth` to activate auth.

I have a custom users mysql table and want to use this instead, with different columns.

Before I am inundated with "Duplicate question" comments, I have read every other (3 pages of Google searches worth) suggestion out there. Maybe I don't understand them or they are for different versions but nothing has worked.

My table name is `users`
My columns are:

```
user_id
user_email
user_password
... etc
```

When I try to log in I get `Username and Password are required` from the validator. When I change the field names I get `column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'`.

I can see from the stack trace that the issue is coming from within the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Foundation` folder but I also know not to modify anything in the vendor folder.

Can someone please help me get this working?

I haven't modified any of the core code. It is exactly as it would be if you ran `make:auth` on a new install. I know this as I have the project git tracked.

Comment: Can you paste the validator lines. Also are you using custom authentication?

Comment: @curious_coder As I said, I haven't changed any routes etc. I don't have any validator lines to paste. Do I have to override a class or 2 somewhere? If so, how?

Comment: Since you are using custom you can use Auth facade in your override function for login

Comment: I can't find anywhere telling me how to do this. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

In your `LoginController.php` file add the override function

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
   if (\Auth::attempt(['user_email' => $request->input('email'), 'user_password' => $request->input('password')])) 
   {
      // Authentication passed...
      return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
   }
}
```